# Haskell SSH Connection

Tags: haskell, ssh

Can anyone point me in the general direction of how to write a simple ssh application that checks if certain credentials pass an SSH server?

I’m looking for something like:

```
sshAuthCheck :: Int -> String -> String -> IO Bool
```

where `Int` is some port, `String` is a username, and `String` is a password.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I know the darcsden code does some SSH stuff. Its source is at http://darcsden.com/alex/darcsden , but I don't know of anything more specific.

Comment: The best I can find on Hackage is [bindings to libssh2](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/libssh2), but it seems to only support public key authentication, not password authentication.

Comment: darcsden.com is an expired domain

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE 2017-04-03**

Since the example under *darcsden.com* has been removed, here's another way to achieve the same thing:

- [Network.SSH.Client.SimpleSSH.openSession](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simplessh-0.2.0.5/docs/Network-SSH-Client-SimpleSSH.html#v:openSession)
- [Network.SSH.Client.SimpleSSH.authenticateWithPasswordSource](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simplessh-0.2.0.5/docs/Network-SSH-Client-SimpleSSH.html#v:authenticateWithPassword)
- [Network.SSH.Client.SimpleSSH.SimpleSSH](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/simplessh-0.2.0.5/docs/Network-SSH-Client-SimpleSSH.html#t:SimpleSSH)
- [Control.Monad.Error.runErrorT](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-Error.html#v:runErrorT)

Steps are as follows:

```
session <- openSession hostname port path_to_known_hosts
auth_session <- authenticateWithPasswordSource session username password
result <- runErrorT auth_session
case result of
    Left simple_ssh_error -> ... {- SimpleSSHError -}
    Right session -> ... {- Session -}
```

- Code not tested
- There are better ways to handle this types of errors. runEitherT is for example purposes only.

**Original answer:**

This library is available:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ssh

which points to an example mentioned by Carl:

http://darcsden.com/alex/darcsden/browse/src/SSHServer.hs